# What is meant by "an easy induction" in the solution to this problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, proof-explanation

I'm given the following problem (Putnam 1984/A2):

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6^n}{(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})(3^n-2^n)}$$

The solution I've been able to find suggests that performing an 'easy induction' shows us that the $n$th partial sum for this series is $$
\frac{6(3^n-2^n)}{(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})}$$

When we take the limit of the $n$th partial sum as $n$ becomes arbitrarily large, we find that the series converges to 2.

I have 2 questions.  1) What's meant by an 'easy induction', and, 2) How does one find the $n$th partial sum in this case?

Comment: "Easy induction" doesn't mean anything specifically. Whoever wrote it was probably trying to say that proving the formula through induction is "easy" in some way.

Comment: You have a stray = in the expression and it is confusing to reuse $n$ as the limit of a finite summation when it was the summation variable.

Comment: @RossMillikan got it.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{6^n}{(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})(3^n-2^n)}=\frac{6(3^k-2^k)}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}$$
We can check that for $k=1$,
$$\frac{6^1}{(3^{1+1}-2^{1+1})(3^1-2^1)}=\frac{6(3^1-2^1)}{3^{1+1}-2^{1+1}}$$
which is true because $3^1-2^1=1$.  Then assume it is true up to $k$ and verify it for $k+1$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{6^n}{(3^{n+1}-2^{n+1})(3^n-2^n)}=\frac{6(3^k-2^k)}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}+\frac{6^{k+1}}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\\
=\frac{6(3^k-2^k)(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})+6^{k+1}}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\\
=\frac{6(3^{2k+2}+2^{2k+2}-6^k(3^2+2^2))+6^{k+1}}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\\=
\frac{6(3^{2k+2}+2^{2k+2}-2\cdot6^{k+1})}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\\
=\frac{6(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})^2}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\\
=\frac{6(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}{(3^{k+2}-2^{k+2})}$$
Maybe "an easy induction" is in the eye of the beholder.